# UPS for client Pcs

Tags: client-server, ubuntu-18.04

I've setup a medical software on a LAN which uses the client/server model.
The server has a UPS and I wanted to know if every client PC needs one too.
What could happen if a power outage occurs while clients are writing to the server?
All of the PCs including the server are running on Ubuntu 18.04.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not a simple question. We need to know underlying technology in details used for both server and client.

Comment: The server has Apache2, MySQL 5.7.29, PHP 7.2.24 and the medical software installed on it. The clients access the software from a browser. Is this info helpful?